# Get query which call to an index

Tags: oracle, oracle12c

I'm using Oracle 12c. And based on DBA_INDEX_USAGE I can determine which Indexes can be used or not.
My question is: Whether is there any way to get exactly query which use an index?

Thanks!

Comment: Check the query plan of your SQL as place to start.  In general, you don't control which index Oracle will use.  Rather, you write the best query you can, maybe using indices, and then let Oracle make the best execution decision.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I know It, but your answer wasn't my desire answer. Now I have a plan to re-design all of Indexes in my DB (~ 500 Indexes), So I have to know the number of query use an index also structure query which call to an Index. 
Many thanks!

Comment: I also use oracle12c and cannot see a view named `DBA_INDEX_USAGE`

Comment: Update: Now I can answer for my question.

To determine which Indexes can be used or not, I use DBA_INDEX_USAGE.

To check exactly query use an index, first I use dba_hist_sqlstat to get SQL_ID, then I use v$sqltext to get all query call to that index.
Note that: fulltext in v$sqltext just store in 7 days.